# dnsmasq TFTP, GNU/Linux workstation, DHCP not responding

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dnsmasq, tftp

I'm attempting to get a TFTP server working, from my workstation.  I've actually attempted this multiple times, never succeeded. I've setup real tftp from a router, but my home router is nothing close to a cisco.  I'm forced to do this from my workstation, and as expected unable to get dnsmasq to repsond to a `dhcping`

This is my plan, TFTP some firmware to my new router... To replace the very limited home router.  The upload is ONLY possible from TFTP, believe me I was looking for any possible alternative.  I'm unable to ZMODEM via serial, and soldering a JTAG would be even more difficult than this plan.  I actually don't need the internet really working from the TFTP server interface, just want that firmware accessible.

eth0, connected to home router:

```
inet addr:192.168.15.109  Bcast:192.168.15.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

eth1, TFTP server, should be static? I'm sure I did this wrong...:

```
inet addr:192.168.15.10  Bcast:192.168.15.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

dnsmasq.conf

```
server=192.168.15.10
interface=eth1
dhcp-range=192.168.15.11,192.168.15.20,12h
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/tftp
```

Route

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ZillaNet        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.15.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.15.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Do I need to create some type of route?
What Should I do to get this working?

Comment: Your configuration looks fine. Is the new router connected to eth1? Can you provide the output of `ip route`? Have you tried to get the router to DHCP or have you only tested with `dhcping`?

Comment: only tested with `dhcping`, updating the OP with `route` output

Comment: just noticed the `dhcping` gave no response, even with the home router :P  I'll give the firmware a shot in morning.

Comment: ..ya no boot, no log in /var/log either.

Comment: There is no way I have this networking correctly configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG I finally got it working.  I followed the instructions on this [page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=716192)!

basically I had my network config incorrect, and in addition was blocking the traffic via iptables.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.16.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.16.0
broadcast 192.168.16.255
```

I did not need to create the manual routes, as I did not use Internet.